# Why it is not possible to create object of a reference in another method in java?

Tags: java, object, methods, reference, pass-by-reference

**Possible Duplicate** : [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

i am trying to do initialization of an array in this way -

```
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 4;
    int[] s = null;
    int[] f = null;
    init(n, s, f);
    System.out.println(s.length);
}
public static void init(int n, int[] s, int[] f) {
    s = new int[n];
    f = new int[n];
}
}
```

but i am getting `NullPointerException` for the `s.length`. so this clear passing the parameter to another method is pass by value. therefor objects are not initialize. 
but when i do swap in to value in a different method then this is working. like -

```
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 4;
    int[] s = new int[n];
    int[] f = new int[n];
    s[0] = 10;
    f[0] = 20;
    System.out.println(s[0] + " " + f[0]);
    swap(s, f);
    System.out.println(s[0] + " " + f[0]);
}
public static void swap(int[] s, int[] f) {
    int t = s[0];
    s[0] = f[0];
    f[0] = t;
}
}
```

on the other hand this isn't swap values.

```
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer a = 10;
    Integer b = 20;
    swap(a , b);
    System.out.println(a + " " + b);
}
public static void swap(Integer a, Integer b) {
    int t = a;
    a = b;
    b = t;
}
}
```

therefor i need some explanation whether java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”? this explanation could help me to understand why it is not possible to create object in another method.

sorry for my bad English. thanks in advance.

Comment: One sets a value, one initializes something (by reassigning). Big difference when it comes to pass by value of reference.

Comment: primitives are passed by value (copy is given), and objects have their pointers passed by value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't work because Java has *pass by value*, not *pass by reference*.

When you declare

```
int[] s = null;
```

then you have a (`null`) reference to an `int[]`. But when you pass `s` to another method, what happens is that a new variable (let's call it `x`) is created, and the reference `s` is copied into it. Any changes to what `x` references will also change what `s` references, because they're the same thing; but changes to `x` itself won't change `s`, because `x` and `s` are two different references to the same thing.

Think of it like this. Your `s` is an entry on a clipboard, and the clipboard entry tells you the number of the box to look in to find the `int[]`. When you pass `s` to a method, you get a *new* entry `x` on the clipboard, with the *same* box number as was under the `s` reference. That means that any operation that looks in the box and changes its contents will affect what you get when you look at what `s` refers to: they both look at the same box number. But if you change the entry on the clipboard for `x`, it won't change the entry on the clipboard for `s`, because they're two different entries.

As another example, think of `s` and `x` as being road signs pointing to the same town. If you change the town that `x` points to, e.g. by introducing a one way system in the town centre, then of course what `s` points to will also have changed. But if you change the road sign `x`, and write a different town's name on it, that won't automatically change the road sign `s` too. They're different signs, but signifying the same thing.

Comment: so basically in the first segment of code, `init` function `s = new int[n]` creates different object that is not pointing my passed parameter from the caller function. that is understandable. thanks a ton.